# Nonparametric hypothesis testing with a recursively defined probability distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I want to apply a nonparametric hypothesis test like the chi-square goodness-of-fit test in a setting where the distribution is defined recursively, but I'm unsure whether the requirement that the samples are independent is fulfilled. More concrete: I consider a random variable $X$ and want to test if its distribution is approximately the following one (it's a simplified version, but it contains the main issue): $$\mathbb{P}(X=0)=1-p, $$
$$\mathbb{P}(X=i)= p\cdot \left( \left( \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \mathbb{P}(X=j) \right)^r - \left( \sum_{j=0}^{i-2} \mathbb{P}(X=j) \right)^r\right) \text{for }i\in \mathbb{N},$$ where $p$ is taken from the real data (from my samples) and $r$ is a fixed integer.
My samples are transactions from a blockchain, so they are created in a specific order and while there definitely are random elements in their creation, the (real) probability that the random variable takes value $i$ for my $j$th sample depends on the values that $X$ takes for the first to $(j-1)$th samples - basically as it is reflected in the formula for $\mathbb{P}(X=i)$, which is how I would justify that I can indeed reasonably apply a hypothesis test on my data, but I'm not entirely sure, so I would appreciate any help. If you need more details to answer, please ask. Thank you very much!